# open tab with routing in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

in this address `localhost:4200/verify` i have a component , in this component i need when user click on button got to other compoent in this route:

`localhost:4200/user/info/3#personalInfo`

in this route i have a component and in that component i have a `mat-tab`
. when use come in this url `localhost:4200/user/info/3#personalInfo` i need to open second tab .

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-segment?file=src%2Fapp%2Finformation%2Finformation.component.html)

**how can i do this work in angular ????**

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the fragment in HTML like:

```
<button [routerLink]="['infos']" fragment="tab2">Got To Tab2</button>
```

Then in the taber component, get access to the fragment,

```
demo1TabIndex = 0;
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  const fragment = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.fragment;
  console.log('fg', fragment);
  // You can do any type of manipulation you want to get the index value and set it to demo1TabIndex variable.
  switch (fragment) {
    case 'tab1':
      this.demo1TabIndex = 0;
      break;
    case 'tab2':
      this.demo1TabIndex = 1;
      break;
    case 'tab3':
      this.demo1TabIndex = 2;
      break;
  }
}
```